# How to support the ‘working-tree-encoding’ attribute in libgit2?

Tags: libgit2

I'm tracking a  file (*.sra) in `libgit2`, and after making a change `libgit2` identified the file as binary and wouldn't diff it for me. I discovered that the file was encoded in UTF-16.

Can `libgit2` be taught to recognize that this file is text and handle it appropriately?

I'm using git, it can set  '`working-tree-encoding`' attribute to merge it,when conflict .

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell from reading [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), `libgit2` does not support `working-tree-encoding`:

> Alternative Git implementations (e.g. JGit or libgit2) and older Git versions (as of March 2018) do not support the working-tree-encoding attribute. If you decide to use the working-tree-encoding attribute in your repository, then it is strongly recommended to ensure that all clients working with the repository support it.